# Tooltip não funciona dinâmico

Tags: ajax, asp.net, asp, tooltip

Observe essa linha:

```
response.write "<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='" & TitleBadge & "' style='margin-right:3px;'>"
```

Essa linha esta dentro de um arquivo que é chamado via ajax. Se eu coloco dentro do html:

```html
<span data-toggle='tooltip' data-original-title='Titulo' style='margin-right:3px;'>
```

Funciona, mas via ajax não.

Já entendi por que, mas ainda não resolvi. Quando inicializa a função tooltip, tudo que tem `title=""` passa a ser `data-original-title=""` e por isso não pega o que vem dinâmico.

Já tentei vir direto com o `data-original`, mas também não foi.

A página que tem o tooltip eu chamo assim:

```
function PegarSemanaConsultaFinan(DataProcura){

    dados = "DataProcura="+DataProcura

    $.ajax({
        url: "financeiro-procura-semana.asp?"+dados,
        Type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            $("#results-div-finan").html(result);
        },
        error: function(){
        }           
    });
}
```

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Comment: Você está usando qual linguagem de programação?

Comment: ASP, mas chamo assim:

Answer (score 1):

O problema que você está tendo é que seu tooltip está sendo adicionado dinâmicamente em sua página.

Tente isso:

```
$("body").tooltip({
selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
});
```

Para mim isso funciona corretamente, mas caso não funcionar, tente usar isso:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','[data-toggle=tooltip]', function(){
    $(this).tooltip('show');
});

$(document).on('mouseleave','[data-toggle=tooltip]', function(){
    $(this).tooltip('hide');
});
```

Comment: Bingo. funcionou o primeiro com o body. muito obrigado pela ajuda. valeu mesmo

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, parabens.